# fatfree sessions, different values in database and echo stmt

Tags: session, fat-free-framework

I have this in my `beforeroute()` of a controller

```
    public function beforeroute()
{
    new \DB\SQL\Session($this->db);

    $mapper = new \DB\SQL\Mapper($this->db, 'users');

    $auth = new \Auth($mapper, array(
        'id' => 'username',
        'pw' => 'password'
    ));

    if (!$auth->login('validuser', '1234')) {
        die('username or password wrong');
    } else {
        echo ($csrf = $this->db->exec('SELECT csrf FROM sessions')[0]['csrf']);
    }
}
```

After I hit the page, I have different values for `csrf` in database and what's been echoed out on page. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `csrf` token is renewed on every request. You see different values on the page and in the database, because the value in the database was updated after your page has rendered.

To be more specific, the SQL Session handler replaces the default php session handler, and that's why the call to `session_commit` within the unload method https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/blob/master/base.php#L1903 (is called when the framework shut down) will update your session database table with the new value.

To have a way to reuse that single `csrf` token for your purpose, just put it back into the session itself:

```
$s = new \DB\SQL\Session($f3->get('DB'));
// old value from last request
echo $f3->get('SESSION.csrf');
// remember current value for next request
$f3->set('SESSION.csrf',$s->csrf());
```

Maybe there`s an easier way, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: I understand that `csrf` gets new value with each new request, but shouldn't
it stay the same as setting and querying here happens in the same
`beforeroute()` method? Isn't that the same request?

Comment: Yes it is the same request, but you are manually querying the sessions table which actually contains different data already, but wasn't persisted yet (that happens in unload). What you can do is to use the mapper behind the session handler instead. $s = new \DB\SQL\Session($this->db); echo $s->csrf(); and not use your own db->exec on the sessions table.